# Tab completion for hosts defined in ~/.ssh/config doesn't work anymore on Yosemite

Tags: bash, ssh, macos

I'm trying to create my `~/.ssh/config` file for simplify my work life on the server connection.

In Mavericks all worked properly and with the <kbd>tab</kbd> I was be able to autocomplete the hostname with file like this:

```
Host test-host-name
    HostName 192.168.1.2
    User root
```

The same configuration on Yosemite have a different behavior. When I type `ssh t` on the shell the <kbd>tab</kbd> does not autocomplete the hostname.

Do someone know if is something changed in Yosemite and now I need to do something to make it work?

Answer (score 54):

You can enable bash shell completion by installing `bash-completion` via [brew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install bash-completion
```

Then add the following to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
. $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

[Source](http://davidalger.com/development/bash-completion-on-os-x-with-brew/)

(Edit: `brew tap homebrew/completions` is deprecated as of 2018.)

Comment: +1 :) When installing bash-completion-1.3.3.high_sierra, it tells me I should add ```[ -f /usr/local/etc/bash_completion ] && . /usr/local/etc/bash_completion```. Could you elaborate on which version (that or yours) should be preferred and why?

Comment: @JanNash That is basically a single line version of that `if` above. Additionally the `$(brew --prefix)` will make it work if your hombrew isn't installing to `/usr/local`. You should use the version posted as the answer.

Comment: This does not work on my M1 Mac.

Answer (score 20):

I assume the shell of your Mac is bash.

You need to complete ssh command, for more detail you can read `man complete`

```
_complete_ssh_hosts ()
{
        COMPREPLY=()
        cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
        comp_ssh_hosts=`cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts | \
                        cut -f 1 -d ' ' | \
                        sed -e s/,.*//g | \
                        grep -v ^# | \
                        uniq | \
                        grep -v "\[" ;
                cat ~/.ssh/config | \
                        grep "^Host " | \
                        awk '{print $2}'
                `
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${comp_ssh_hosts}" -- $cur))
        return 0
}
complete -F _complete_ssh_hosts ssh
```

Don't forget you need to `source` the file to get the new command to load in your terminal. or You can put this code in .bash_profile

Comment: Yep, the shell is bash. Why in Maveriks I didn't need to do this things?

Comment: No, I've tested just now. I can't do that in Mavericks by default.

Comment: `comp_ssh_hosts=$(awk -F , 'FNR== NR && ! /^#|\[/ {field = $1} FNR != NR && /^Host / {field = $2} {hosts[field]} END {for (host in hosts) {print host}' "$HOME/.ssh/known hosts" "$HOME/.ssh/config")`

Comment: A quick tip, this command won't find your host if you use tab instead of spaces. So if you are indenting your .ssh/config file, keep an eye to this

Comment: I get error ```.bash_profile:21: command not found: complete``` on M1 Mac

Answer (score 4):

From [this article on MacWorld](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100113142633883).

Copy/paste the following into `~/.bash_profile`:

```
complete -o default -o nospace -W "$(/usr/bin/env ruby -ne 'puts $_.split(/[,\s]+/)[1..-1].reject{|host| host.match(/\*|\?/)} if $_.match(/^\s*Host\s+/);' < $HOME/.ssh/config)" scp sftp ssh
```

You'll then need to either restart your terminal or type `source ~/.bash_profile` (note that the latter will only work in your current tab).

Comment: Did not work for me. But https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/168168/136365 did. I think it's best to avoid relying on ruby for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I'm not sure how to respond directly to nelson's answer since I haven't built up enough reputation to comment on it yet, but on my machine running El Capitan, `^M` was being appended to all of the host names from my config file.  I had to either add `\r` to my `$IFS` variable or remove/substitute all instances of `\r` from the output of the second `cat`.  In the end, I did the latter by adding `tr '\r' '\n'` to make that command chain look like this:

```
cat ~/.ssh/config | \
        grep "^Host " | \
        awk '{print $2}' | \
        tr '\r' '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

[Nelson's answer (above)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/168168/361120) doesn't tell you which macOS version he's using.

For macOS 10.14, after installing `bash-completion` with:

```
brew install bash-completion
```

The installer told me to add this line to my .bash_profile (which I put in my .profile instead) and it worked:

```
  [[ -r "/usr/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh" ]] && . "/usr/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/):

```sh
$ sudo port install bash-completion
```

Then add the following to your ~/.bash_profile:

```bsh
if [ -f /opt/local/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /opt/local/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Existing answers seem like hacks to me. The proper way is to compile OpenSSH with editline/readline/history support, it’s that easy!

Honestly, I cannot possibly fathom WHY any sane person would’ve built it without this, as it gives all the desirable features (up-arrow command history, tab-completion of local and remote filenames, etc.) with zero caveats. I enabled it when I built OpenSSH 8.7p1 on my jailbroken iPad but I'm sure it works equally well anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

You can add entries in /etc/hosts and use them in host name autocomplete:

```
"ssh @" + [TAB]
```

Reboot is required for system to reload this file.